error: attribute 'android:name' in <activity>tag must be a valid Java class name
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
   > Android resource linking failed
     C:\Users\chauk\AndroidStudioProjects\Testft_android\build\app\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:52: error: attribute 'android:name' in <activity> tag must be a valid Java class name.

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml to check the required configuration.
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">



    <application
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="testft_android">
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.testft_android.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:taskAffinity=""
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
    <!-- Required to query activities that can process text, see:
         https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility and
         https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_PROCESS_TEXT.

         In particular, this is used by the Flutter engine in io.flutter.plugin.text.ProcessTextPlugin. -->
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        </intent>
    </queries>
</manifest>


For others to be able to help you, it looks like you need to provide [example]. In general take a look at [ask] to improve your question.

The error you're seeing indicates an issue with the android:name attribute in the <application> tag within your AndroidManifest.xml. Specifically, android:name="${applicationName}" is not resolving to a valid Java class name, which is required by Android.
Solution
The android:name attribute should either:

Reference a fully qualified Java class name (e.g., "com.example.testft_android.MyApplication") if you've created a custom Application class.
Be omitted if you don't need a custom Application class.

Steps to Fix

Remove or Correct the android:name Attribute:

Option 1: Remove the android:name line entirely if you do not need a custom Application class:
<application
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="testft_android">


Option 2: If you have a custom Application class (e.g., MyApplication in com.example.testft_android), specify the full class name:
<application
    android:name="com.example.testft_android.MyApplication"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="testft_android">




Sync and Rebuild the Project:
After updating AndroidManifest.xml, sync your project with Gradle and try rebuilding it.


This will resolve the issue.

Its possible you have a typo, but you can simplify this to
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"

Or whatever the name of you application class is. If you don't have an overridden application class, you do not need this attribute.


error: attribute 'android:name' in tag must be a valid Java class

<application
    android:name="${applicationName}"


clean and rebuild the project, check if it works leave the 2nd step.
remove android:name property and rebuild the project.

